# Free project collaboration tools - SVN + tasks + auto deployment

Tags: svn, project-management, build-automation, collaboration

I'm looking for a free / open source tool which will allow me to set up easily tasks manager integrated with SVN repository and auto-deployment tool (so that each commit is autodeployed to the http server). It need to integrate tasks users with SVN users etc.
Must run linux!
What are your types?

Comment: If you are asking for some kind of continuos integration server check out Hudson

Comment: both, but self deployed is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *[GO Cruise Server + Mingle + Twist](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/go/2.0/help/welcome_to_cruise.html)*

http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/forms/form/go/download

Have a look if its suits you requirement for **Continuous Integrated(CI)** build/deployment process !

Answer (score 3):

*Not free but a great tool in a  great price.*

[Assembla](http://Assembla.com) - Ticketing, SVN Repository, Individual Project Space, Team Collaboration

Other plans include FTP access that could make it possible to setup a build automation process.